# (Practical) Applications or RNN

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, application

I have been googling for a list of practical applications of Recurrent Neural Networks for some time, but did not find a reasonable reference list.

Most of the things are about text generation which seems to be rather for fun/academic research. I do not have anything against text generation. I am looking for a list of practical applications, with some direct commercial impact.

I know that I can simply open scholar.google.com and search for individual contributions. Is there any list of 10-20 most remarkable applications?

Can you help me with that list?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Image captioning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4555.pdf)

[Sentiment analysis](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html) (this is an example of LSTMs in Theano)

[Question answering](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P15-2116)

[Speech recognition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5778)

[Anomaly detection in time series](https://www.elen.ucl.ac.be/Proceedings/esann/esannpdf/es2015-56.pdf)

Wikipedia has a section on applications in [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory#Applications) article.

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand that RNNs deal with "series" of data. It can be time series or it can be sentences which can be thought of as series of words.

One thing very powerful about RNNs is that it allows you to deal with series which are of different length. Having said that, any thing that looks like series or time series can potentially be handled by RNNs.

Few more examples or applications:

1. Log data analysis (web data)
2. Sensor data analysis (Time series)
3. Translation
   https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq
4. Named entity recognition (you'll have to use with word2vec) 
   https://github.com/monikkinom/ner-lstm
5. Video classification
   http://www.ijcsit.com/docs/Volume%206/vol6issue02/ijcsit20150602189.pdf

And many others that contain series/time series data.

Comment: would you mind to add some references?

Comment: I've just added some first found search results. You can dig deeper with proper key words...